# Loading models in Keras takes exponentially longer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a series of Keras models saved in hdf5 format (including both structure and weights). These models are based on pre-trained [DenseNet121 from keras.applications](https://keras.io/applications/#densenet), and have been further fine-tuned with custom datasets.

For production use, I need to have all these models loaded in memory at the same time.

```py
from keras.models import load_model

model_names = ['birds', 'cats', 'dogs', 'phones']
models = dict()

for name in model_names:
    path = 'models/{}.h5'.format(name)
    m = load_model(path)
    models[name] = m
```

Loading time seems to get exponentially longer the more models have already been loaded. Indicative values are:

- it takes 1 minute to load `birds.h5`
- it takes 5 minutes to load `cats.h5`
- it takes 7 minutes to load `dogs.h5`
- it takes 15 minutes to load `phones.h5`

All models are based on the same structure and each h5 file takes 82Mb on disk. I'm running this on an AWS `p2.xlarge` instance equipped with one single GPU.

**Questions:**

- why is the loading time growing with the number of models already loaded?
- is it normal or am I doing something wrong?
- how can I improve the overall loading time?

Comment: You could try a funky hack that is: join the four models in one with a single input (call each model with the input and create a model from this input to each output). Save this model and see if it's loaded ok. You can retrieve each model from it later.

Comment: @DanielMöller sounds interesting but I'm not sure I'm completely following. Could you detail a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proven answer, I'm detailing it here from the comment above for you to test.

> Join the 4 models into a single one.

**How to do that?**

Load them and wait all that time (this is still not production).

Now:

```
common_input = Input(compatible_shape)  #assuming all models have similar inputs

outputs = []
for name in models:
    outputs.append(models[name](common_input))

common_model = Model(common_input, outputs)
```

Save this `common_model` and see how much time it takes to load in a new session.

You can retrieve each model from it with `common_model.layers[i]`. See in the summary which `i` is which layer. If you defined your submodels with names, it's easier: `common_model.get_layer(model_name)`.

Comment: Alright, now it makes perfect sense. I'm going to try this.